# Uso del vocabolo "antifona" in senso figurato

Tags: word-usage

Mi hanno spiegato che il termine "antifona" può essere usato con il senso figurato di qualcosa che viene detta in modo implicito e velato, ma che si può capire ascoltando attentamente il discorso (in catalano e in castigliano parliamo di una "indirecta"). Ma come posso usare questo vocabolo con questo significato? Sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/antifona/) e su altri dizionari ho trovato il modo di dire

> capire l'antifona

in cui la parola "antifona" ha questo senso. Posso usarla però in altri tipi di espressioni? Se la risposta è affermativa, potreste farmi qualche esempio?

Comment: *Capire l'antifona* è l'unico uso di questo significato che mi venga in mente. Per una parola generica con questo significato userei il *sottinteso*.

Comment: Concordo. Occorre tenere conto che nei modi di dire è l'insieme delle parole ad avere un certo significato. Se separi gli elementi, i significati tornano quelli originari. Quindi "capire l'antifona" va usato tutto insieme.

Comment: Ho lasciato solo un commento perché non mi sembrava abbastanza materiale per una risposta, ma se nessuno ha niente di meglio da offrire trasformo volentieri il mio contributo in qualcosa che Charo possa accettare. Incidentalmente, la persona che ha votato negativamente sarebbe gentile se lasciasse almeno una spiegazione.

Comment: Sì, @DenisNardin, puoi scriverlo come risposta.

Comment: Non è chiaro cosa Charo stia cercando. Nella mia risposta ho dato tre diversi usi figurati di antifona ma a Charo non sembravano sufficienti. "Capire l'antifona" è solo uno di questi usi per cui non capisco come possa essere la risposta che l'OP sta cercando.

Comment: @Gio la mia impressione è che volesse sapere se c'erano altre espressioni dove "antifona" è usata nel senso di "sottinteso", non quali siano i significati della parola "antifona".

Comment: @Gio: Mi dispiace se non sono riuscita a spiegarmi bene. Qualcuno mi aveva spiegato che la traduzione del vocabolo catalano "indirecta" all'italiano era "antifona", o perlomeno io l'avevo capito così. Ma poi non trovavo esempi con questo significato su Internet. Grazie alla risposta di Denis, però, adesso ho capito che posso usare questo termine con questo significato soltanto nel modo di dire "capire l'antifona". Non posso dire "Maria ha detto un'antifona a Giovanni", per esempio.

Comment: @Charo - capisco, ma potresti dire "smettila di ripetere la stessa antifona"  se qualcuno insiste a farti presente la stessa cosa in maniera indiretta.

Comment: @Gio: Ma, se ho capito bene il Treccani, questo non ha lo stesso significato. Cioè, quando se dice "ripetere la stessa antifona", quello che se ripete continuamente non è necessariamente qualcosa di sottinteso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'espressione *capire l'antifona* è l'unico uso di questo significato che mi venga in mente. Una parola italiana che abbia questo significato più generalmente è [*sottinteso*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sottinteso/)

> **sottintéso** agg. e s. m. [part. pass. di sottintendere]. – Che non è espresso, che non è detto esplicitamente
>
> *(Diz. Treccani)*

Answer (score 1):

In realtà l'antifona è una sorta di ritornello ripetuto durante i salmi responsoriali delle celebrazioni liturgiche. Il salmista recita o canta alcune strofe e l'assemblea risponde con l'antifona.
Come ogni ritornello, essa sintetizza in poche parole il messaggio che il salmo vuole veicolare.
L'antifona contiene dunque il precetto morale che il fedele deve comprendere e rispettare.

Per estensione il termine si può usare, anche al di fuori del contesto religioso, a indicare un messaggio sotteso a un discorso o a un comportamento che chi parla o agisce ci vuol veicolare.

Comment: L'antifona si dice all'inizio e alla fine; il ritornello si chiama, appunto, ritornello.